# Angular 6 and Firestore: best way to loop through and update each Document in AFS Collection?

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, angular6

This is an Angular 6 and Firestore project. I am trying to iterate through and update each document in my `articlesCollection`. A click event triggers the method that does the loop. The problem is, sometimes the method loops through the collection only once. Other times it loops infinitely. Is there a problem with my method? Is there a better way to loop through and update each doc in a collection?

Edit: When I hard reload localhost:4200, the first time I trigger the method it loops through once. If I trigger the method a second time, it loops infinitely.

```
featureArticle(article) {
    const articleArray = this.articlesCollection.snapshotChanges();

    articleArray.subscribe( payload => {
      payload.forEach( item => {
        const ID = article.id;
        const articleID = item.payload.doc.data().id;
        const articleTITLE = item.payload.doc.data().title;
        const articleToUpdate = this.articlesCollection.doc(`${articleID}`);
        if (ID === articleID) {
          articleToUpdate.update({
            isFeature: true
          });
        } else {
          articleToUpdate.update({
            isFeature: false
          });
        }
        alert(`${articleTITLE} updated`); <-- LOOPS INFINITELY
      });
  });
}
```

The template:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let article of articles | async">          
  <div (click)="featureArticle(article)">
     {{ article.title }} 
  </div>   
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so my fix here was to create an empty `IDs = []` variable in the component. In the constructor, I looped through my `articlesCollection` with `snapshotChanges().foreach()` and pushed all of my document (article) IDs to the array. My `featureArticle(article)` method could then loop through the `IDs` array and compare `article.id` to each `ID`. If there was a match, I did X. If there wasn't a match, I did Y.

The point of this was to write a method that would set any given Article's `isFeature?` property to `true` while simultaneously setting all other Articles `isFeature?` properties to `false`.

```
export class AdminArticleListComponent {
  articlesCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Article>;
  IDs: Array<any> = [];

  constructor( stuff here ) {
    this.articlesCollection = this.afs.collection('articles'); 
    this.articlesCollection.snapshotChanges().forEach( a => {
      a.forEach( item => {
        const id = item.payload.doc.data().id;
        this.IDs.push(id);
      });
    });

  }

  featureArticle(article) {
    for (let id of this.IDs) {
      const document = this.articlesCollection.doc(`${id}`);
      const articleID = article.id;
      if (id === articleID) {
        document.update({
          isFeature: true
        });
      } else if (id !== articleID) {
        document.update({
          isFeature: false
        });
      } else {
        console.log('Error updating feature Article');
      }
    }
  }

}
```

And the template:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let article of articles | async">
  <tr>
      ... other cells ..
      <td class="featureCell" (click)="featureArticle(article)">
          <ng-container *ngIf="article.isFeature">
              <span class="greenCheckmark">&#9989;</span>
          </ng-container>
          <ng-container *ngIf="!article.isFeature">
              <span >&#9989;</span>
          </ng-container>
      </td>
  </tr>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are listening on changes and acting on changes. And acting on changes will trigger the listener since you are changing something.

You will ofcourse remain in an endless self-imposed loop.

A soulution would be: listening on changes on some trigger doc A. This could be a simple doc for just this purpose: listening when there has to be changes done on doc B.
Then this onchanges on A listener is triggering the Method you wanted to call in the first place to update any doc B. So if doc B is updated, there won't be a infinite loop, since doc A isnt getting any change triggers if doc B is updated.

Comment: Thank you. That makes some sense. I'm trying a different approach without `subscribe` and using `valueChanges()` instead of `snapshotChanges()`.  Will update this post shortly.

Comment: Btw if you learn any better method, let me know. I had that same Problem when I worked with firebase. That was my workaround solution which did its job, but this can't be a final way to solve this.

Comment: Yeah, is it not odd that it's really difficult to find a good way to loop through Angular Firestore Collections? I mean, I have looked at dozens and dozens of sites trying to find a solution to this. It seems like it ought to be a really basic thing.